# Solving equation of motion using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, physics, differential-equations

```
#import libraries
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp
from sympy.plotting import plot as symplot

#initialize symbols
delta1,delta2,mass,youngs,width,thickness,length = sp.symbols("delta_1 delta_2 m E b t L") #spring
permeability,magnetization,radius,height = sp.symbols("mu_0 M R h") #magnetic replusion
rho,dragconst = sp.symbols("rho Cd")

#EOM
EOM=Eq(mass*Derivative(delta1, dt,2)-((delta1**2)*youngs*width*thickness**3)/4*length**3-((pi*permeability*(magnetization**2)*radius**4*((delta2-delta1)**4)+(10*(delta2-delta1)**2)*thickness**2+(4*(delta2-delta1)**3*thickness+12*(delta2-delta1)*thickness**3+4*thickness**4))/((4*(delta2-delta1)**2)*(((delta2-delta1)+2*thickness)**2)*((delta2-delta1)+thickness)**2))+Rational(-1, 2)*rho*(Derivative(delta1, dt,1)**2)*dragconst*width*length,0)
display(EOM)
dsolve(EOM,delta1)
```

```
−(1)22−32134+221−240(−1+2)4+44+3(−121+122)+102(−1+2)2+4(−1+2)34(−1+2)2(−1+2+)2(−1+2+2)2=0
 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24300/1246088876.py in <module>
     14 EOM=Eq(mass*Derivative(delta1, dt,2)-((delta1**2)*youngs*width*thickness**3)/4*length**3-((pi*permeability*(magnetization**2)*radius**4*((delta2-delta1)**4)+(10*(delta2-delta1)**2)*thickness**2+(4*(delta2-delta1)**3*thickness+12*(delta2-delta1)*thickness**3+4*thickness**4))/((4*(delta2-delta1)**2)*(((delta2-delta1)+2*thickness)**2)*((delta2-delta1)+thickness)**2))+Rational(-1, 2)*rho*(Derivative(delta1, dt,1)**2)*dragconst*width*length,0)
     15 display(EOM)
---> 16 dsolve(EOM,delta1)
     17 
     18 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\ode\ode.py in dsolve(eq, func, hint, simplify, ics, xi, eta, x0, n, **kwargs)
    602 
    603         # See the docstring of _desolve for more details.
--> 604         hints = _desolve(eq, func=func,
    605             hint=hint, simplify=True, xi=xi, eta=eta, type='ode', ics=ics,
    606             x0=x0, n=n, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\deutils.py in _desolve(eq, func, hint, ics, simplify, prep, **kwargs)
    207     # recursive calls.
    208     if kwargs.get('classify', True):
--> 209         hints = classifier(eq, func, dict=True, ics=ics, xi=xi, eta=eta,
    210         n=terms, x0=x0, hint=hint, prep=prep)
    211 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\ode\ode.py in classify_ode(eq, func, dict, ics, prep, xi, eta, n, **kwargs)
    940 
    941     if func and len(func.args) != 1:
--> 942         raise ValueError("dsolve() and classify_ode() only "
    943         "work with functions of one variable, not %s" % func)
    944 

ValueError: dsolve() and classify_ode() only work with functions of one variable, not delta_1
```

I have a EOM of an oscillation and I want to solve the delta1 value and output as an equation but there seems to be error that I can only use one symbol for the derivation.

Can anyone tell me what did I miss and how to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare that `delta1` is a function of `dt` and do something like:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Function, Rational, pi, dsolve

delta1 = symbols("delta_1", cls=Function)  # declare delta1 as a function

dt = symbols("dt")  # set dt

delta2, mass, youngs, width, thickness, length = symbols("delta_2 m E b t L")
permeability, magnetization, radius, height = symbols("mu_0 M R h")
rho, dragconst = symbols("rho Cd")

# set the equation
eq = mass * delta1(dt).diff(dt, 2) -
    ((delta1(dt)**2) * youngs * width * thickness**3) / 4 * length**3 -
    ((pi * permeability * (magnetization**2) * radius**4 * ((delta2 - delta1(dt))**4) +
    (10 * (delta2 - delta1(dt))**2) * thickness**2 +
    (4 * (delta2 - delta1(dt))**3 * thickness +
    12 * (delta2 - delta1(dt)) * thickness**3 +
    4 * thickness**4)) / ((4 * (delta2 - delta1(dt))**2) *
    (((delta2 - delta1(dt)) + 2 * thickness)**2) * ((delta2 - delta1(dt)) +
    thickness)**2)) +
    Rational(-1, 2) * rho * delta1(dt).diff(dt)**2 * dragconst * width * length

# solve the equation
dsolve(eq, delta1(dt))
```

Note that (after a while of calculating) sympy says that it can't solve this equation, so there's either more debugging to do (which could be quite likely and a more detailed reading of the [sympy ODE examples may be required](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/solving/solve-ode.html)) or it's either not analytically solvable or not within sympy's ability to solve.

Comment: Almost all nonlinear ODEs do not have analytic solutions. I would be surprised if this one does.

Comment: Uhhh thanks for answering my question, it seems that I still have a long way to go.